# SliderLayout always taken wrong picture

Tags: android, slider

For example

When you pick no "smp4", the picture must be no smp4, but in my case, my SliderLayout always pick all or wrong pictures

[image: the wrong picture]

and this is

```
 private void getGambar() {
    String url = "https://arizalway.000webhostapp.com/api/getgambar.php?StudioMusik=" + id;
    Log.i(TAG, url);
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int numData = response.length();
                    if (numData == 0) mDemoSlider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    else {
                        JSONObject slider_studio;
                        Log.i(TAG, "On Response get gambar");
                        String[] gambar_sekolah = new String[numData], nama_sekolah = new String[numData];
                        HashMap<String, String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
                            try {
                                slider_studio = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                gambar_sekolah[i] = slider_studio.getString("gambar");
                                nama_sekolah[i] = slider_studio.getString("nama");
                                url_maps.put(nama_sekolah[i], "https://arizalway.000webhostapp.com/api/slider_studio/" + gambar_sekolah[i]);
                            } catch (JSONException je) {
                                Toast.makeText(DetailSekolah.this, "JSON ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(DetailSekolah.this);
                            textSliderView.description(name).image(url_maps.get(name)).setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);
                            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                            textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra", name);
                            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                            mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.ZoomOut);
                            mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                            mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                            mDemoSlider.setDuration(30000);

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
```

my friend says ( and searching in web too ) the name picture in hosting and name that picture in database must be same but i already did it but no luck

[image: file in host]

[image: database picture]

[image: id from database studio]

thank you, sorry for my bad english

Comment: gambar mean picture in indonesian

Comment: Check the id information. When you want to access any data from your database you need to use id info. Using id info better and healtier than yours. As i understand from your statements that you have tried to access your data with their title. But its wrong.  You can start  checking your intents by using id info of rows.

Comment: for example mister JDeveloper?

Comment: Normally, if you use SQLite database you have a model class which you hold your values such as id, name, description etc... After that you need to build your database classes. You can search from internet and find easily document about SQLite. What I'm talking about id is auto increment which is provided by the database. Each row has own id and when you want to access it, enough to send id with your intent. For example when you click your image, you can get all info with using its id. I couldnt explain exactly but some searching on web is better.

Comment: or maybe my conecction php is wrong ? https://arizalway.000webhostapp.com/api/koneksi.jpg

Comment: still looking for answer.

Comment: I know little mysql database my dear, I was talking about SQLite database. But the way of solution is that you need to get key id of rows. İf you dont, you can not I think

Comment: For example you need to use id row of second picture in bundle. Not Name!

Comment: sorry for my foolness, but i already did it with "id" but no luck, trying change there and this and read your answer, trying to understand, maybe i try it again, thx for helping me
if dont mind  @JDevoloper, please look full code from this activity https://pastebin.com/sJBWN5Eb , thank you again

Comment: link is not working

Comment: work for me, but try this link https://pastebin.com/jUg1smGp

Comment: I have reviewed the code but there is nothing different in the part you are having trouble with. I can not detect the problem from here I'm sorry this issue is beyond me If you have made my point

Comment: i got the answer, adding this code to con.php  "$id = (isset($_GET['StudioMusik']) ? $_GET['StudioMusik'] : '');"